# Update LDAP attribute in AD with Python

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory, ldap, openldap, ldap3

When I try to update an Active Directory attribute with this code:

```
dn = (
    "CN=user_ldap,OU=dept_name,OU=Application,"
    "OU=Service Accounts,OU=Domain Users,DC=company-corp,DC=global"
)

# define the server
server = ldap3.Server(
    "ldaps.company-corp.global", get_info=ldap3.ALL, port=636, use_ssl=True
)

# define the connection
conn = ldap3.Connection(server, dn, psw, auto_bind=True)

conn.start_tls()

userID = "jdoe"

# perform the Modify operation
conn.modify(
    f"CN={userID},OU=managed,OU=Domain Users,DC=company-corp,DC=global",
    {"displayName": [(ldap3.MODIFY_REPLACE, ["Doe, John D"])]},
)

print(conn.result)
```

I get the following error:

> {'result': 32, 'description': 'noSuchObject', 'dn': 'OU=Managed,OU=Domain Users,DC=company-corp,DC=global', 'message': "0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100241, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:\n\t'OU=Managed,OU=Domain Users,DC=ssnc-corp,DC=global'\n\x00", 'referrals': None, 'type': 'modifyResponse'}

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NO_OBJECT` error generally means an object with the specified DN (in this case `cn=jdoe,ou=managed,ou=domain users,dc=company-corp,dc=global`) cannot be found.

It's possible to get the error when the service account doesn't have *rights* to read the record or when the fully qualified DN is incorrect.

To eliminate an incorrect fully qualified DN, you could try searching for an object (like do a search for `sAMAccountName=LogonIDGoesHere`) and retrieving the DN value.

To eliminate access, you can check an account's effective permissions to an object using Active Directory Users & Computers.

- On the "Security" tab, click "Advanced".
- In the advanced security settings window, click on the "Effective Access" tab.
- Click the 'select a user' link to select your service account then click "View effective access" to see if something like 'read all properties' or 'read general information' are allowed.